# Creating tensorflow::Tensor from Eigen::Tensor

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen, tensor

How should I create a tensorflow::Tensor from Eigen::Tensor? I could just copy the elements over one-by-one, but I hope there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public api to create a tensorflow::Tensor from an Eigen::Tensor without copying the data. However, you can create a tensorflow::Tensor and interpret it as a Eigen::TensorMap using the following apis: 

`tensorflow::Tensor tf_tensor(tensor_constructor_args);
// For the general case:
Eigen::TensorMap<type_params> eigen_tensor = tf_tensor.tensor<Type, NumDims>();
// shortcuts if you know the tensor is a matrix/vector/scalar
Eigen::TensorMap<type_params> eigen_matrix = tf_tensor.matrix<Type>();
Eigen::TensorMap<type_params> eigen_vector = tf_tensor.vector<Type>();
Eigen::TensorMap<type_params> eigen_scalar = tf_tensor.scalar<Type>();`

This will avoid a copy. Moreover, Eigen tensors and tensormaps share the same apis, so you can use them interchangeably.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Benoit Steiner, but this doesn't help me too much. But maybe I'm trying to solve a wrong problem. The reason I'm using Eigen::Tensor is that I can easily slice them. So I read from the file all the samples and each iteration pass to the model corresponding slices. Can I do this with pure tensorflow::Tensor?

Comment: There is no easy way to slice a tensorflow::Tensor. However TensorFlow provides a [tf.slice](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice) operation that you can use to slice your input data and feed each sample individually at each iteration.

Comment: You answer seems to be showing how to create an Eigen::TensorMap from a Tensorflow::Tensor, but the question is the other way around.. how to create a Tensorflow::Tensor from an existing Eigen::Tensor (which is the same problem I have which led me to this question).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might be useful:

```
Eigen::Tensor<float, 3> TensorflowToEigen(const tensorflow::Tensor& tensor) {
  const tensorflow::TensorShape dims = tensor.shape();
  Eigen::Tensor<float, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> rm_tensor =
      tensor.tensor<float, 3>();
  // Change to ColMajor. swap_layout changes the ordering of dimensions, so we
  // shuffle them back.
  Eigen::Tensor<float, 3> cm_tensor =
      rm_tensor.swap_layout().shuffle(Eigen::make_index_list(2, 1, 0));
  return cm_tensor;
}

tensorflow::Tensor EigenToTensorflow(const Eigen::Tensor<float, 3>& tensor) {
  const Eigen::DSizes<int64_t, 3> dims = tensor.dimensions();
  // Change to RowMajor. swap_layout  changes the ordering of dimensions, so we
  // shuffle them back.
  Eigen::Tensor<float, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> rm_tensor =
      tensor.swap_layout().shuffle(Eigen::make_index_list(2, 1, 0));
  tensorflow::Tensor tf_tensor(
      tensorflow::DT_FLOAT,
      tensorflow::TensorShape({dims[0], dims[1], dims[2]}));
  tf_tensor.tensor<float, 3>() = rm_tensor;
  return tf_tensor;
}
```